# Removing a portion of text using regex?

Tags: php, html, regex

Here is what I have up to this point:
The function `.*?` takes everything until the first "this character". For example `$html = preg_replace('/alt=".*?"/', '', $html);` replaces everything between `alt="` and other quotation mark with nothing. My problem is now I have to deal with multiple characters. Here is the portion of text I want to replace :

```
<a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/TheWindowsClub?a=tjWEu-9hLFk:Jv9oVdSsx2A:yIl2AUoC8zA"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/TheWindowsClub?d=yIl2AUoC8zA" border="0"></img></a> <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/TheWindowsClub?a=tjWEu-9hLFk:Jv9oVdSsx2A:qj6IDK7rITs"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/TheWindowsClub?d=qj6IDK7rITs" border="0"></img></a> <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/TheWindowsClub?a=tjWEu-9hLFk:Jv9oVdSsx2A:gIN9vFwOqvQ"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/TheWindowsClub?i=tjWEu-9hLFk:Jv9oVdSsx2A:gIN9vFwOqvQ" border="0"></img></a> <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/TheWindowsClub?a=tjWEu-9hLFk:Jv9oVdSsx2A:I9og5sOYxJI"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/TheWindowsClub?d=I9og5sOYxJI" border="0"></img></a> <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/TheWindowsClub?a=tjWEu-9hLFk:Jv9oVdSsx2A:cGdyc7Q-1BI"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/TheWindowsClub?d=cGdyc7Q-1BI" border="0"></img></a></div><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/TheWindowsClub/~4/tjWEu-9hLFk" height="1" width="1" alt=""/>
```

Unlike last time I can't use quotation marks or other such character. I have to delete the whole line. One thing I thought about was to do something like this:

```
$html = preg_replace('/<a href=".*?(alt=""/>)/', '', $html);
```

I thought that using the above code would find the last portion in this segment and replace everything inside but it replaces nothing. Please suggest what should I do?

After running above line of code the output should be nothing. It should remove all this code block.

Comment: i can't follow what you are saying, you seem to be referring to some previous question and i dont know where is that.. all details should be here that are needed. Show examples of what end result would be etc.

Comment: If this is part of a larger HTML document you really should use an HTML parser. I can't tell exactly what it is you're trying to replace though? The alt tag?

Comment: No I am trying to replace all the code. I wrote above. I am editing the code.

Comment: Can you provide what you want the output to be? I think the solution here is going to be to use an HTML parser though, not a regex.

Comment: I have updated the question @chris85. The output should be nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a\s+href.*(alt="[^"]*")?>
```

or without quotation mark :

```
<a\s+href.*(alt="[^"]*"){0,1}>
```

We match everything that starts by `<a`, is followed by **at least** one space, then by any character until the character `>`, **before which** you may have **zero or one** iteration of the string `alt=""` containing **anything but** a `"`.

Comment: Ivan, could you please explain the code so that I can modify it in future if need arises. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not lazy but I strongly advise you to use a website like https://regex101.com/ that will explain you everything line by line ;) But I added a little explanation and fixed a mistake  !